# What does the "new campaign" button do in Starcraft 2?

Tags: achievements, starcraft-2

I've just finished the campaign and I'm thinking about redoing the campaign to see other options and all. And I was wandering what the "new campaign" button does.

Does it erase my achievements ?

Does it reset the portraits I've unlocked?

There is some kind of score thingy... I made a thousand points. Does it reset?

Does the button do anything else ?

Comment: I added a contains spoiler tag because I didn't know about any secret mission.  Maybe we could use this tag for questions that contain spoilers on the side?

Comment: @Mechko : I'm very sorry for that. I've edited to question to remove the spoiler. So I removed the spoiler tag. You should remove or edit your own comment since it contains the spoiler too.

Comment: lol it's ok.

Comment: Actually it's perfectly fine...  You're allowed to ask spoilerific questions here as long as you keep the tag there jst in case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting a new campaign does not erase achievements, unlocked portraits, or decals.

All it does is start the missions over, from the beginning, so you can, for instance, take the alternate routes on the 3 "choice" missions (and see the after-mission movies, which you aren't privy to when simply replaying the mission via the archive).

It may also be the only way to lower your elapsed time for the "Hurry Up it's Raid Night" achievement. (On account of being able to skip some missions)

Comment: Tested and verified.

Comment: I saw the after mission movies when replaying from the archive.

Answer (score 1):

The new campaign button will just over write your previous campaign.  All the achievements and portraits are saved along with your achievement points.  The credits you got for technology and credits for beating each mission will disappear because its a new campaign.

You could always open a saved game from a previous campaign.  But its just like overwriting a previous saved game, you are just overwriting your previous campaign :P

Answer (score 0):

"New Campaign" does simply that. It starts a new campaign. It starts you over at the beginning of the campaign and you can start over.

Any achievement earned is saved, so you don't have to worry about that. All portraits and decals are associated with achievements, so those are kept as well.

If I'm understanding you correctly, the "score thingy" is probably the number of achievement points you've earned, so those will stay.

If you want to, you can save your previous campaign, so you can come back to it if you want to.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't hit the button myself, but my friend recommends making a new character before you do that, since you lose at least some of the stuff that you've unlocked.  He was unclear on exactly what is lost.

EDIT: If you want access to old campaigns, you should make saves before hitting the new campaign button.  you can access the old campaigns through these saves.